# How does lw in mips actually work?

Tags: mips

Is this statement a valid one?

```
lw $t0, 21($s0)
```

`$s0` contains the decimal `2022`.

In my opinion this is invalid, because based on what I know, The address specified by the offset + the register should always be a `multiple of 4`. Is this correct or not?

An extension to this question based on the answer provided, The exception will arise just on looking at the address at `$s0` or after the computation of the address `21+$s0` ?

Comment: @Sibi: you should open a new question for your doubt.

Answer (score 3):

The execution of that instruction when $s0 contains the decimal 2022 will raise an exception, due to the effective address (2041=2022+21) is not aligned properly.

Comment: Corollary: the OS kernel can emulate unaligned accesses at a very significative performance cost (e.g. on Linux/MIPS, see `arch/mips/kernel/unaligned.c`).